# How to use regex in atom editor to combine redundant classes in CSS

Tags: css, regex, atom-editor

I am looking for a way to find redundant classes in CSS and combine them easily.
For example I have:

```
#quote {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 3.6vmin;
}

#quote {
    text-align: center;
}
```

but not necessarily next to each other, and I want to find one or more of this class to combine it into example:

```
#quote {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 3.6vmin;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Now I know that I can do this by hand, but doing it with regex seems more efficient, especially for large code.
I tried typing #quote {*} into find and replace, but my syntax must be off or something because I am getting no matches. Yes I do have regex turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though i haven't had the chance to test it fully, the following code shall give you an idea. It will parse the `cssText` variable and reduce it by removing the redundant selectors and properties regardless of how many of them exist. It will of course keep only the last definition of the repeated properties. The CSS object is stringified into a neat looking text with an option of justifying the selector properties to the right or left which is provided by a boolean argument to the `reduceCSS` function. You can also play with it at https://repl.it/CEkL/4.

```js
var  cssText = '#quote { padding-bottom: 20px; font-size: 3.6vmin; } #quote { text-align: center; } .pinky{font-family: verdana; background-color: pink; font-family:impact;} .topic{font-size: 5vmin;} #quote {font-size: 3vmin; font-family: verdana;} #quote ~ pinky_pinky{background-color: blue;}';
function reduceCSS(cssText,rightJustify) {

  function parseAndReduce(ct){
    var allSelectors = ct.match(/[^}]+(?={)/g),
        selectorList = {};
    allSelectors.forEach((e,i,a) => a.indexOf(e) == i && (selectorList[e.trim()] = {}));
    Object.keys(selectorList).forEach( e => {
                                              var r = new RegExp(e + "\\s*{\\s*([^}]*)","g"),
                                              t = "";
                                              while (!!(res = r.exec(ct))) res[1].split(";").forEach( s => {
                                                if ((s = s.trim()) !== ""){
                                                  t = s.split(":");
                                                  selectorList[e][t[0].trim()] = t[1].trim();
                                                }}); 
                                            });
    return selectorList;
  }

  function stringify(co,rj){
    
    function getMaxLength(arr){
      return arr.reduce((p,c) => p.length >= c.length ? p:c,"").length;
    }
    
    function justify(s,n,r) {
      return r ? s = " ".repeat(n) + s : s = s + " ".repeat(n);
    }
    
    var     ct = "",
     selectors = Object.keys(co),
    sMaxLength = getMaxLength(selectors);
    selectors.forEach( s => {
                              var      n = sMaxLength - s.length,
                              properties = Object.keys(co[s]),
                              pMaxLength = getMaxLength(properties);
                              s = !!n ? justify(s,n,rj): s;
                              ct = ct + s + " {\n";
                              properties.forEach( p => {
                                                         var n = pMaxLength - p.length;
                                                         p = !!n ? justify(p,n,rj) : p;
                                                         ct = ct + " ".repeat(sMaxLength+3) + p + " : " + co[s.trim()][p.trim()] + ";\n";
                               });
                              ct = ct + " ".repeat(sMaxLength+1) + "}\n";
                            });
    return ct;
  }
  
  return stringify(parseAndReduce(cssText),rightJustify);
}
document.write("<pre>" + reduceCSS(cssText,true) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this below:

**`to find`**

```
(?im)([.#][\w-]+)\s*\{([^}]+)\}\s*\1\s*\{([^}]+?)\}
```

**`to replace`**

```
$1{$2$3}
```

I believe that your editor supports at least `PCRE flavor`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
^(.*?)\s*#quote {(.*?)\s*}(.*)(#quote {)(.*?)(}.*)$
```

Substitution:

```
\1\3\4\2\5\6
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zG1pZ3/2)

Input:

```
#any1 {
}

#quote {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 3.6vmin;
}

#any2 {
}

#quote {
    text-align: center;
}

#any3 {
}
```

Output:

```
#any1 {
}

#any2 {
}

#quote {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 3.6vmin;
    text-align: center;
}

#any3 {
}
```